# Ideal generated by a subset of a lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

In George Grätzer book, *Lattice Theory : Foundation*, there is some fundamental result I am not sure to interpret correctly. The owner of the book will find it page 32. It is the second statement of the Lemma 5. Here it is :

> Consider a lattice $L$. Consider $H$ a subset of $L$. Then consider
>   $I$ the ideal generated by $H$, being the smallest ideal of $L$ (from
>   inclusion point of view) containing $H$.
>
> The lemma states that :
>
> $$I = Id(H) \iff I = \{x | x \leq h_0 \lor \ldots \lor
> h_{n-1},\;for\;some\;n\geq1\;and\;h_0,\ldots,h_{n-1}\in H\}$$

From what I understand, it means :

$$\forall x \in I, \exists n \in \Bbb{N}^*, \exists \{h_0,\ldots,h_{n-1}\}\in H^n,x \leq h_0 \lor \ldots \lor h_{n-1}$$

However, a bit later in the book, George Grätzer states the following to prove another result (page 34) :

> $I$ is an ideal generated by subset $C$ of $L$. Let us take $t \in I$.
>   From previous lemma, we can affirm that $\exists c \in C, t \leq c$.

I do not understand how the previous lemma makes it possible to do such a statement.

If anybody is able to tell me where I am wrong, would be really grateful.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong.

In page 34, $C$ is not just any subset of the lattice; it is a convex sub-lattice.
Thus, if $t \leq c_1 \vee \cdots \vee c_k$, for some $c_1, \ldots, c_k \in C$, then $c \in C$, where $c = c_1 \vee \cdots \vee c_k$; thus $t \leq c \in C$.

Comment: Thanks a lot amrsa. To be perfectly clear, you only use the "sublattice" property of $C$. It is fundamental in this theory of course.